# Why does the Action Link depend on the current request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

For example, when I visit http://www.nerddinner.com/Home/About/, the About tab points to http://www.nerddinner.com/Home/About/ which is what I expect.

However, If i were to visit http://www.nerddinner.com/Home/About/WhyDoesThisLinkChange, not only is this page valid but the About tab also points to http://www.nerddinner.com/Home/About/WhyDoesThisLinkChange. Why does ASP.NET MVC do this and how do i prevent it from doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your routing setup?  Something is wrong with it I'd suggest.  The second example URL shouldn't map to the same action.

You probably have a parameter in the routing - and correctly MVC is preserving this parameter.

In principal if you have

/product/view/17

Controller = product

Action = view

{productId} = 17

So in this case it makes sense to preserve the Id of the product across requests to the same action.

But in your case you don't really want both those URLs to map to the same place.  That said once you are there - with the second URL - it makes sense for MVC to use the same URL to get back to the same action.

UPDATE: If you want to explicitly stop a parameter being accepted for this URL then you need to make the parameter accepting routing option more specific so it excludes this URL, or put in a routing option above it without a parameter than accepts only the Home/About URL.

Comment: Yes i believe there is a parameter in the routing but how would I prevent MVC from preserving its value after a request? Also, you can view the source code here: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/. It's an open source mvc application to help noobs like me.

Comment: You can explicitly set parameters in ActionLink - see the MSDN list of signatures.  So you can explicitly set it to null.  But really I think you need to look at the underlying logic of the routing.  If you accept a parameter in that location in the URL then it makes sense to preserve it.  I think the underlying problem is you don't want to accept a parameter there - why do those two URLs point to the same page - does that make sense in the context of the universe of URLs your application supports?  Once you accept they do point to the same page - then your links make sense as they are.

Comment: Ran out of space... so to summarise as you say in your post 'not only is this page valid but..'.  In this case I'd suggest it's the not only bit that's introducing the problem rather than the but.